# Subset in R between 2 Months over a Range of Days

Tags: r

I have been subsetting data using this code below.

```
setwd("C:/Users/A/Desktop")
vf <- read.csv("Height.csv", header = TRUE)
#Insert month and Day(s) desired
vf1 <- vf [ which(vf$Month==9 & vf$Day>0 & vf$Day <31), ]
vf2 <- vf1[c(-1,-2,-3)]
```

When I try to subset from April 20th to May 20th, I use this code (shown below) and it subsets nothing

```
vf1 <- vf [ which(vf$Month==4 & vf$Month ==5 & vf$Day>19 & vf$Day <32), ]
```

I also try another way (below) and get an error

```
vf1 <- vf [ which(vf$Month==4 & vf$Day>19 & vf$Day <31), which(vf$Month ==5 & vf$Day>19 & vf$Day <32), ]
Error in `[.data.frame`(vf, which(vf$Month == 4 & vf$Day > 19 & vf$Day <  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Can someone please explain what is being done incorrectly?

Comment: `vfMonth` can never be both 4 and 5 at the same time, so `vf$Month==4 & vf$Month==5` will never be `TRUE`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich so how does one make it a factual statement? `vfmonth==4&5`? I am sorry, that is not really helpful. just being honest.

Answer (score 1):

As @JoshuaUlrich said, the month of one observation can't be two values at the same time. 
Something like that would work:

```
vf1 <- vf [ which( vf$Month==4 & vf$Day>19 | vf$Month ==5 & vf$Day <32 ), ]
```

So you are saying if Month is 4, Day must be larger 19 **or** if Month is 5, Day must be smaller 32.

Comment: @ja-thomas Yes that is what I was trying to do, just have to change the #32. Can you explain why there has to be a `|` in the code? I'm still learning R. Thanks!

Comment: @LyzandeR Can you explain what you mean?